# Read part of ORIGINAL JSON string with all spaces and indents

Tags: c#, json

My client posts following json data in the body to my API, is there an easy way to get hold of the `abc` node's value (including the `{}` as well) as JSON string from `HttpContext.Request.Body`? the most important thing is **I need to keep all original spaces or indent if any**.

P.S the `abc` is always the first node, while `def` is the last node.

Thanks

```
{
   "abc": {
     ....
   },
   "def":"..."
}
```

Comment: Hi Ming! When it comes to working with JSON in C#, Newtonsoft is your best friend. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: You could use Newtonsoft's `JsonTextReader` to locate the element's start and end indices.  From there you could get a substring from the original JSON.

Comment: `JsonTextReader` doesn't report its position in the underlying `Stream`, see the discussion thread at [How to get detailed position information from JsonTextReader](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53108483), which is unanswered.  You might be able to get what you need by recording the `IJsonLineInfo` of the `abs` node then re-reading the file to get the whitespace; see e.g. [Newtonsoft.Json - Getting corresponding line numbers of deserialized objects from JSON for better error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26050036).

Comment: @dbc take these two JSON as example, `{     "abc" :"def"}` and `{ "abc"     :"def"}` the `LinePosition` of the `abc` property is the position of `:`, but it doesn't tell whether it is 5 spaces at front of `abc` and 1 space after it or the other way round.

Comment: @Ming - `JsonTextReader` doesn't provide the information you want.  However, with the `JsonTextReader`'s `IJsonLineInfo` of the `"abc"` property itself, and the `IJsonLineInfo` at the time the reader is positioned on the end token `}` of the value of `"abc"`, you might have enough information to extract the formatted JSON with some manual parsing of the contents of the file loaded into a `string`.

Comment: @dbc no, there are four token types: start, propertyName, value and close. Lets take start and property name as examples, when it is start, `LinePosition` is on `{`, when it is propertyName, position is on `:`, it can only tell total number of spaces between `{` and `:`, it cannot tell whether it is 4 spaces in between `{` and property name or property name and `:`

Comment: Right, you'll need to manually scan backwards in the JSON `string` from the position of the `:`, skipping past spacing, then the property, then more spacing, to get exactly what you want.  Honestly a nuisance but it's the best I can suggest since Json.NET doesn't pass information about spacing on to consumers of `JsonTextReader`.  (Or you could use a `Regex` as you decided below.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I decided to read the string out of `Stream` first then use `Regex` as solution for this special case, I know it is not great, but because spaces and indent is one of crucial requirements, for sake of simplicity, I am happy to trade off performance for now.