# Newtonsoft.Json - Getting corresponding line numbers when deserializing to JObject

Tags: .net, json, json.net, json-ld

I'm deserializing json-ld based json to validate it against things like schema.org. Because of this I can't deserialize into known object types, so I do the generic deserialization into a JObject.

If I encounter an error, like an unsupported property, I want to reference back to the source code. e.g. have line numbers can column positions.

I thought I had the answer here:

[Newtonsoft.Json - Getting corresponding line numbers of deserialized objects from JSON for better error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050036/newtonsoft-json-getting-corresponding-line-numbers-of-deserialized-objects-fro)

But it does not work when deserializing to JObject. ReadJson is not called.

Is there any way to get position info when deserializing to JObject?

```
var lineNumberConverter = new LineNumberConverter();

var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonLdScript.TextContent, new JsonSerializerSettings()
  {
    Converters = new[] { lineNumberConverter }
  });

    public class JsonPosition
    {
        public int StartLine { get; set; }
        public int StartColumn { get; set; }

        public int EndLine { get; set; }
        public int EndColumn { get; set; }
    }

    public class LineNumberConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public Dictionary<object, JsonPosition> Positions = new Dictionary<object, JsonPosition>();
        public override bool CanWrite
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Converter is not writable. Method should not be invoked");
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return true;
        }
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader,
                                        Type objectType,
                                        object existingValue,
                                        JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JsonPosition position = null;

            var jsonLineInfo = reader as IJsonLineInfo;

            if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.Null)
            {
                if (jsonLineInfo != null && jsonLineInfo.HasLineInfo())
                {
                    position = new JsonPosition() { StartLine = jsonLineInfo.LineNumber, StartColumn = jsonLineInfo.LinePosition };
                }
            }

            var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

            if (position != null)
            {
                if (jsonLineInfo != null && jsonLineInfo.HasLineInfo())
                {
                    position.EndLine = jsonLineInfo.LineNumber;
                    position.EndColumn = jsonLineInfo.LinePosition;
                    Positions.Add(jObject, position);
                }
            }

            return jObject;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `JToken` implements `IJsonLineInfo` explicitly.  If you need line information to be loaded for a `JToken` hierarchy, call `JToken.Load()` (or `JToken.Parse())`.  If you don't, you can continue to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>()` as this is the default behavior for both.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/ecsLcg for a demo.  Or do you need something else?

Answer (score 0):

I'm now using the JsonTextReader which is more complex to set up, but more flexible for my needs. The reader object contains current position info which means I can get positions down to each token as it reads through the json. Checking before and after a read and I get the range of text to highlight.